# What is a good way to display initials of multiple persons in Profile picture

Tags: gui-design, design, profile

We have a display picture, where we show the initials of a user if his picture is not present. Example, John Doe will see JD enclosed in a circle.

There are profiles where we have multiple users in a group.

Example: John Doe, Xyz abc, Xyz Wta and there is no group name as such. In such cases what is the best way to display initials. I got suggestion to split the circle like a wheel and show each initial in a quardent.

What is the best way to do some thing like that? Considering we will Limit number of Users to three at max. I cannot even think of how to show it.

Comment: Maybe you need to do something completely different for Groups? They do not match the solution you are using for individuals who do not have a picture. e.g. you have to be careful this does not become a "square peg, round hole" solution.

Comment: Yes. But I am trying the Wheel kind of display. But I myself was thinking how do they do normally.

Comment: Are there likely to be more more than 4 people in a group? If there are more than 4 then how would you decide which 4 initials to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not make it a goal to show the initials of all the group participants. My hunch is the interface will become too crowded.

As a reference, these icons are from Cisco's Spark app:

[image]

They signify:

- A conversation between multiple people in an unnamed group.
- A user without a profile picture. Spark chooses not to display initials for users - perhaps to differentiate them from the groups below. In my opinion, this is only useful if most people have a profile picture, or you will end up with multiple identical icons in the list.
- Two groups with initials "O" and "C".

Showing multiple participants by stacking the icons on top of each other is fairly common. Just stack two, not more - two means "multiple" in this context.

*Perhaps* you could show the initials for the frontmost person, but I remain hesitant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are limited options:

- make the circle bigger
- Make the initials smaller

For Groups, a larger circle *and* smaller initials is the only way to make this work when you split the circle into 4 quadrants.

Comment: NO this is for email so not clicking and JS.

Comment: Can you put up a mock-up so that we can understand the context?

Comment: You just mentioned Email and JS, which wasn't mentioned before. We don't discuss JS here because this is a UXSO.

Comment: As you mentioned clicking on circles to drill down, I was trying to say that is not possible.  Example we are currently showing like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GvOrl.png) but what if there are two or three initials ? What is the best way to show?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe represent each individual in the group with a smaller circle, like this:

Larger groups:

[image: Group representation - 9 people]

Smaller groups:

[image: Group representation - 4 people]

This would give you more circles to work with for representing larger groups.

Comment: But that does waste space...

Comment: This would be equivalent to a single profile circle, pending that the size was acceptable. But yes, if you want to show all members, it will get crowded.

Answer (score 0):

## Do not show any initials.

The concept of profile for single persons and groups is entirely different, so you shouldn't show the initials for people in the group.

Think about this: you're adding a lot of friction, in visual terms this is really confusing, and in terms of usability nobody would get what all that *noise* means. It's really important to understand whether you're dealing with an individual or a group, so you shouldn't try to *disguise* the group as an individual.

But if the reasons above are not enough, think about *lack of versatility*. Take a look at a very common case you will face:

---

Group A was formed by `AB, CD, EF` and thus you show the initials for these individuals.

Now `GH and IJ` join the group, while `AB and CD` leave it.

Now the group is.... `ABCDEF` even though `AB and CD` are not part of the group. Furthermore, `GH and IJ` are not represented, which makes no sense at all.

So.... you can change the group to `EFGHIJ`. Easy, right? Well, think twice: now anyone that interacted with `ABCDEF` will not know who is `EFGHIJ`!

---

In short: get rid of those initials: they're really bad UX, they bring a lot of problems, and they bring no benefit at all!

**PS: Also, aren't you allowing your users to name a group *any way they want?***